# regex parse store in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I am coding to find names and hobby from text file and store it in Details(mysql Table).The details table consists of 'Names' and 'Hobbies'.I cant able to store to my database.

```
import MySQLdb
import re
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()
with open('qwer2.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:


        patterns = [
         a,b= re.compile('My name is (\w+) and my hobby is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
         a,b= re.compile('Me (\w+) and my interest is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
        ]

        match_result = patterns[0].match(line) or patterns[1].match(line)
        name, hobby = match_result.groups()             
        cursor.execute('''INSERT into Details (Names, Hobby)
                          values (? , ?)'''%(a,b)
```

My text file is a paragraph:

```
My Name is Casssandra and my Hobby is Cooking.
My name is Archana and my hobby is Playing.Me Adarsh and my interest is Programming.
Me Leela and my interest is Baking.My name is John and my interest is Gaming.
```

Output:

```
Names      |  Hobby

Cassandra   Cooking  
Archana     Playing
Adarsh      Programming
Leela       Baking
John        Gaming
```

Please help me rectify my program to store into the table.

Comment: if hobby is `dancing and singing`

Comment: Please modify my entire program,my program its getting worser after every editing.

Comment: two things are involved in your code 1.) regex 2.) database

Comment: what about if name include **first name last name**. I have added that part also in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing SQL parameters with string formatting, and that doesn't work. Pass in the parameters as a *separate* argument:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT into Details (Names, Hobby)
                  values (%s, %s)''', (name, hobby))
db.commit()
```

You need to use `%s` for the placeholders when using the MySQLdb database adapter, and you need to commit the transaction as well.

Your `patterns` setup is not valid Python; if you wanted to match multiple patterns, then make that a proper list:

```
patterns = (
    re.compile('My name is (\w+) and my hobby is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile('Me (\w+) and my interest is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
)
```

and just loop over these patterns until one matches:

```
for pattern in patterns:
     match_result = pattern.match(line)
     if match_result:
         name, hobby = match_result.groups()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> patterns = (
...     re.compile('My name is (\w+) and my hobby is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
...     re.compile('Me (\w+) and my interest is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
... )
>>> lines = '''\
... My Name is Casssandra and my Hobby is Cooking.
... My name is Archana and my hobby is Playing.Me Adarsh and my interest is Programming.
... Me Leela and my interest is Baking.My name is John and my interest is Gaming.
... '''.splitlines()
>>> for line in lines:
...     for pattern in patterns:
...         match_result = pattern.match(line)
...         if match_result:
...             name, hobby = match_result.groups()
...             print(name, hobby)
... 
('Casssandra', 'Cooking')
('Archana', 'Playing')
('Leela', 'Baking')
```

All put together that becomes:

```
import MySQLdb
import re

patterns = (
    re.compile('My name is (\w+) and my hobby is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile('Me (\w+) and my interest is (\w+)\.', re.IGNORECASE),
)
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base

with open('qwer2.txt','r') as file, db as cursor:
    for line in file:
        for pattern in patterns:
             match_result = pattern.match(line)
             if match_result:
                 name, hobby = match_result.groups()
                 cursor.execute(
                     '''INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby)
                        VALUES (%s, %s)''',
                     (name, hobby))
                 break
```

This also uses the database connection as a context manager (which gives you a cursor), this auto-commits the changes when the `with` block is done without errors.

Comment: Also, `a,b` seems inadequate. Should use `name, hobby` instead.

Comment: i did that without regex and it does no work,could u please modify my program?

Comment: @adarshram: You really don't know what you were doing, were you?

Comment: i know but not know how would i store to database,that is making me worse.

Comment: i get follwing errors:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/maydbt1.py", line 22, in <module>
    (name, hobby))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'Names' at row 1")

Comment: @adarshram: then you matched a name that doesn't fit the database column constraint. Create a bigger column or skip such names.

Comment: My name match the database column and what is meant by create bigger column/skip such names?I mean for insert it just creates so what is need for making column bigger?

Comment: @adarshram: your table schema has constraints for each column. Say it is a `VARCHAR(100)` column, then you can only fit names of up to 100 characters in that column. You tried to insert a name that was bigger than that limit.

Comment: @adarshram: You either need to skip such names (`if len(name) > 100: continue`), truncate the name (`name = name[:100]`), or fix your database schema.

Comment: Works great!As i metioned its a paragraph,so many names are not taken,but it takes perfect from individual lines.But it doenot take from a sentence eg:"Me Leela and my interest is Baking.My name is John and my interest is Gaming."It takes leela and hobby but not John and Hobby.Thats the problem?Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: @adarshram: That's because there are two sentences on one line; `re.search()` will only find the first, not all matches. Use `re.findall()` then and loop over all the results. However, you cannot keep asking new questions in comments; this doesn't really scale. If you continue to struggle with that, ask a new question.

Comment: please check my new question over the above problem at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723345/regex-print-all-words-in-sentence        .Hoping for reply!

Answer (score 2):

Get the matched group from index 2 and 4.

```
/(?:(My Name is|Me) )(.*?) and (?:my (Hobby|interest) is )([^\\.]*)./i
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4sE0/8)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?:(My Name is|Me) )(.*?) and (?:my (Hobby|interest) is )([^\\.]*).', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"..."

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: first extract the required data from line using above regex that matches *singing and dancing* as well. inserting in database is separate task.

Comment: first do code for extracting the vales then extend your code to insert it in database. I have no idea about database insertion code.

Comment: could u provide a sample of extracted output after using ur code?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the cursor correctly and the only thing you need to do is to execute SQL statements which you can do it by calling execute on cursor object. Also, I recommend you to checkout the MySQLDB documentation.